# Error: NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this somewhat basic code for extracting data from a page, the issue is that a week ago it stopped working and I get the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`, maybe something has changed in the code the page, I have tried to fix it but I can't. help me, thank you.

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

    headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
    Ubuntu Chromium/71.0.3578.80 Chrome/71.0.3578.80 Safari/537.36",
    }

    url = "https://www.weplay.cl/new-arrival-funko-pop#/w/0/list/all/"

   req = requests.get(url)
   soup = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')
   contenedor_de_productos = soup.find(class_="products-grid products-grid grid")
   lista_de_productos = contenedor_de_productos.find_all('li', class_='product-item')

   for producto in lista_de_productos:
       texto_producto = producto.find(class_='product-item-name').text
       texto_producto = texto_producto.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '').replace(',', 
       '').replace('"', '').strip()
       print(texto_producto)
```

Comment: Check what is `contenedor_de_productos` just before you use `find_all`?

Comment: Yes, something has changed on the page, the HTML element with class `"products-grid products-grid grid"` is not in there anymore, thus `contenedor_de_productos` becomes None, and you get the error in the next line. To fix it, look at the new HTML, find the parts you are interested in, and write a new Python script to extract it from the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they have changed the website structure, earlier they might be getting all the data in HTML page in the first request itself, but now the data is coming in different request. The data is coming in JavaScript request and they are rendering it so your XPATH and your code is not working. If you see the response from the given URL you are getting like "Just a moment..".

To make your code work we have two solutions i.e

1. Try to use selenium browser, here browser will only make the request in the back-end and render the data so you can take the data and parse.
2. Identifying the JavaScript request and making that request, here [link](https://www.weplay.cl/pub/media/mageplaza/search/default_0.js) they are making this request to get all the data in back-end and loading the data, so you can make this request and take whatever data you want.

I see you need product names so you can simply get all those product names from above request.